# Need help getting an effect on a header and with a button

Tags: html, css, button, header

I am trying to get a certain effect on a header for a mockup. It has white glow almost not noticeable. You will see it in this picture i provide behind the title and sub title. How can i get that glow effect with css? I do have a header with the entire thing but is that a good idea to use an image for an entire header? Also i want those two lines near the subtitle. Is it possible to code those lines? And last, the button "order now", will that be possible to make with css or should i just use an image of that and link it?

mockup

[image]

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ezdr3xdg/1/       [what i currently have]

```
    <header>
    <h1>Taffies Cupcakes</h1>
    <h2>Fresh and tasty</h2>
</header>



body{
    background-color:#e7d2c9;
}

header h1{
    font-family:georgia;
    font-size:46px;
    color:#784f3d;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:50px;
}

header h2{
    font-family:segoe script;
    font-size:32px;
    color:#846a5f;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: in order of your questions: use CSS gradients / yes / yes / use an image as img src or background. Now you have enough to learn and show us how you do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this is possible to do in CSS 3, I wouldn't recommend it though. Using an image for the button and the header is the best idea if you want it to look the same in all browsers. If you  want to do it in CSS anyway try this:

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
    <h1>Taffies Cupcakes</h1>
    <h2><div class="line"></div>Fresh and tasty<div class="line"></div></h2>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header > .shadow {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    margin: 0px 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 200px 100px white;
}
header h2 > .line {
    height: 1px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 5px 20px;
    background-color: #846a5f;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

As the other answers have mentioned, `radial-gradient` is probably the way to go here. Just apply it to the `header` element instead of using my version with box-shadow (which might be a little hacky to some).

**Update for the button:**

HTML:

```
<button class="special"><div class="icon"></div><div class="headline">ORDER NOW</div><div class="description">We deliver in 24 hours</div></button>
```

CSS:

```
button.special {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #784f3d), color-stop(1, #846a5f) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #784f3d 5%, #846a5f 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#784f3d', endColorstr='#846a5f');
    background-color:#784f3d;
    color: #e7d2c9;
    text-align: left;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 42px;
}
button.special > .icon {
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    /*background-image: url('triangle-button.png')*/
    position: absolute;
    margin: 5px;
}
button.special > .headline {
    margin-left: 42px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
button.special > .description {
    margin-left: 42px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ezdr3xdg/17/

Comment: In that case i will use the  image since i do want it to look the same. I sliced the header in Photoshop but should i include the background as well since the background of the whole page is the same color anyways? Also what if the page wasn't similar colors?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, the only reason not to create an image with a transparent background is if you want to support ancient browsers like IE 6. Go with a transparent image above a background set with CSS `background`or `background-color` property.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CSS radial-gradient()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient)

## *[DEMO 1:](http://jsfiddle.net/ezdr3xdg/6/)*

```
body {
height: 100vh;
background-color: #e7d2c9;
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center top, ellipse farthest-corner, #fff 0%, #e7d2c9 50%);
}
```

[image]

## *[DEMO 2:](http://jsfiddle.net/ezdr3xdg/2/)*

```
body{
    height:100vh;
    background-color:#e7d2c9;
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center top, ellipse farthest-corner, #fff 0%, #e7d2c9 100%);
}
```

[image]

[*DEMO 3:*](http://jsfiddle.net/ezdr3xdg/15/)

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #e7d2c9;
    position:relative;
}
body:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: -150px;
margin-left: -100px;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border-radius: 50%;
   z-index:-1;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.42);
box-shadow: 0 0 40px 64px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.42);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have update your jsfiddle with a starting template of sorts. Its CSS# gradients and border-radius. http://jsfiddle.net/ezdr3xdg/7/

the button:

```
<div id="order_now">
<div id="triangle-right"></div>
<div id="text">
ORDER NOW
<div id="sub_order">we deliver in 24hours</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:
The Button:

```
#order_now{
    background: linear-gradient(#846a5f, brown);
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#sub_order{
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-style: italic;
}

#triangle-right { 
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-top: 25px solid transparent; 
border-left: 50px solid white; 
border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
display: inline-block;
}

#text{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The Background:

```
body{
    background:linear-gradient(to right, red, blue, red);
}
```

this should be enough to get you started.